# installing the latest MySQL security update on macOS 10.12 Sierra

Tags: mysql, macos

We're still running MySQL (community server) on macOS 10.12 Sierra (because Apple has gutted later versions of macOS and macOS Server and we don't want to go there just yet). It appears the latest MySQL security updates (October 2018) no longer support macOS with the 5.6.x track. The 5.7.x and 8.x tracks now only list installers for 10.13 High Sierra and 10.14 Mojave.

So, the **question** is: can you install the latest MySQL 5.7.24 on macOS 10.12 Sierra and will it run without problems?

I'm okay if it's simply "unsupported" and will install but if it specifically won't install/will cause problems I would like to know before upgrading. I've searched the MySQL web site for information on this but there is nothing.

I asked this question on the MySQL forums and got no response. Hope someone here can help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I can now confirm, after extensive testing, that MySQL 5.7.24 does NOT work on macOS 10.12 Sierra. It will spawn too many files for its process and eventually die requiring a full restart of the whole computer - you can't just kill and restart MySQL. With no security updates available for older versions of MySQL, this now makes MySQL useless on anything but macOS 10.13 High Sierra or later. Thus, given the awful state of macOS Server, your days of running a decent macOS Server with MySQL are now numbered. Time to start testing alternate operating systems and switch…